# How to programmatically open and display a jp2 file on android?

Tags: android, jpeg2000

I am new on android development, I have a JP2 file (jpeg 2000) image and I want to write an app to load and display it on Android device.  Where do I start?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gemalto's [JP2 for Android](https://github.com/gemalto/JP2ForAndroid) library, based on [OpenJPEG](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg).

Add the dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.gemalto.jp2:jp2-android:1.0'
```

and use the following code to convert the JJ2000 bytes to an Android bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new JP2Decoder(jj2000Bytes).decode();
```